# What is the right way to exit the interactive CLI of the command "rev"?

Tags: bash, cat, rev

Please check the code below and notice the difference between exiting the cat command and rev command

```
heer@heer-pc:~$ cat
mark
mark
^C
heer@heer-pc:~$ rev
mark
kram
^Cheer@heer-pc:~$
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The key combination, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, closes stdin and then `rev` (or `cat` or any other program that reads stdin) will close.

Comment: Is important to know that Ctrl+D sends EOF, which causes most of programs to exit gracefully.